# How to get json string from login php result?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I should create a simple website together with an android application that get data from the same database. I have no problems in android but in html I can not examine the json string.
How to get the json result from the php file to login?

in html...

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <form action="login_user.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter your 
              username" id="username">
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter your 
              password" id="password">
    <input type="button" name="login" value="Login" id="login"> 
</form>



<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#login').click(function(){
        var username = $('#username').val();
        var password = $('password').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "login_user.php",
            method: "POST",
            response: {username:username, password:password},
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function(response) {
                // if response is true open 2nd page html
                // else error message

            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

in php file...

```
    <?php

$username = $_POST['username']; 
$password = $_POST['password'];  

require("connection.php");
if (!$conn) {
    // Esito negativo connessione
    $response["response"] = false;
    $response["log"] = "Error connecting to database"; // Messaggio che verrà visualizzato  
    echo json_encode($response); // Restituisce la stringa Json 
} else {
    $query = "select * from users where username = '$username' and password = '$password'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    $row = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if ($row > 0) {
        // Esito negativo connessione
    $response["response"] = true;
    $response["user"] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    echo json_encode($response); 
} else {
    $response["response"] = false;
    $response["log"] = "User not found!";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
mysqli_close($conn);
}
   ?>
```

I need to examine the json string on the first html page and if the response returns true then it goes to the second page

Comment: For one thing, you forgot the `#` in `$('password')`.

Comment: 2nd; use a prepared statement for this and not storing plain text passwords; use `password_hash()` for this before you go live with this; if you do. Otherwise, you might find your database compromised/deleted one day.

Comment: I'm voting this as a typographical error.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Yes, I know I have to encrypt my password, this is just a test. But over $ ("#password") What's wrong? Why doesn't it work? Could you correct the code so that it can understand and continue independently? Thanks in advance

Comment: In your `$.ajax` call, I believe the field name should be `data` not `response`.

Answer (score -1):

I think your AJAX call should look like this:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "login_user.php",
        method: "POST",
        response: {"username":username, "password":password},
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(response) {
            // if response is true open 2nd page html
            // else error message

        }
    });
```

You must have your parameters names in quotes.